Constructing an invertible matrix from vectors with elements ±1
Let $n$ be an integer greater than 1, and consider an $n$-tuple whose elements take eihther $+1$ or $-1$. For example,
\begin{equation}
    \eta_i = (a_{i,1}, a_{i,2}, \cdots, a_{i, n}) = \underbrace{(+1, -1,\cdots, +1)}_{n}.
\end{equation}
There are $2^n$ such distinct $n$-tuples, and for each tuple $\eta_i$, we consider an $n\choose{2}$-tuple $\xi_i$ of the form
\begin{equation}
    \xi_i = (a_{i,1}a_{i,2}, a_{i,1}a_{i,3}, \cdots, a_{i,n-1}a_{i,n}),
\end{equation}
In other words, each element in $\xi_i$ is a product of two distinct elements in $\eta_i$.
We then choose $n\choose{2}$ tuples from $\xi_1$ to $\xi_{2^N}$ to create an $n\choose{2}$ $\times$ $n\choose{2}$ matrix $M$:
\begin{equation*}
M = \begin{pmatrix}
\xi_{k_1} \\
\xi_{k_2} \\
\vdots \\
\xi_{k_{n\choose{2}}}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
We would like $M$ to be invertible. For any integer $n > 1$, is it possible to choose $\xi_{k_1}, \cdots \xi_{k_{n\choose{2}}}$ from $\xi_1, \cdots, \xi_{2^N}$ so that $\det M$ is non-zero? If so, is there a systematic way of choosing $n \choose{2}$ such $\xi_i$'s?

I think it is more convenient to think of $\xi_i$ as a symmetric matrices $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & a_{i,1} a_{i,2} & a_{i,1} a_{i,3} & \dots & a_{i,1} a_{i,n} \\ a_{i,2} a_{i,1} & 0 & a_{i,2} a_{i,3} & \dots & a_{i,2} a_{i,n} \\ a_{i,3} a_{i,1} & a_{i,3} a_{i,2} & 0 & \dots & a_{i,3} a_{i,n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{i,n} a_{i,1} & a_{i,n} a_{i,2} & a_{i,n} a_{i,3} & \dots & 0 \\\end{bmatrix} = \eta_i^\top \eta_i - \operatorname{diag}(\eta_i)^2$$
but of course everything can be translated to the language of $\binom{n}{2}$-tuples.
What we want is to find $\binom{n}{2}$ $(\pm1)$-vectors $\eta_i$ such that the corresponding matrices $\xi_i$ are linearly independent, that is, form a basis of the space of symmetric matrices with $0$ on the diagonal.
This is indeed possible: note that if two $(\pm1)$-vectors $\eta_i$ and $\eta_j$ are only differ in the $k$-th coordinate, then the matrix $\frac{\xi_i - \xi_j}{2}$ is nonzero only in the $k$-th row and $k$-th column, and this row and column contain the common entries of $\eta_i$ and $\eta_j$, and a linear combination of such matrices can give every zero-diagonal symmetric matrix. This means that the matrices $\xi$ corresponding to all $(\pm1)$-vectors span the required space, and so we can choose from them a basis.
Looking at this construction in a bit more detail, we can say that we can in fact choose a basis from $\binom{n}{2} + n + 1$ matrices which correspond to vectors with at most two $-1$ coordinates, because this set allows us to construct matrices which are zero except for one row and one column, and the nonzero row and column can have all $+1$ entries or only one $-1$ entry.
To go further, we need to find relations between those $\binom{n}{2} + n + 1$ matrices. Let $$\eta_0 = (+1, \dots, +1),$$ $$\eta_i = (+1, \dots, \underset{\text{$i$th}}{-1}, \dots, +1) = \eta_0 - 2e_i,$$ $$\eta_{ij} = (+1, \dots, \underset{\text{$i$th}}{-1}, \dots, \underset{\text{$j$th}}{-1}, \dots, +1) = \eta_0 - 2e_i - 2e_j,\text{with $i \neq j$}$$
and let $\xi_0$, $\xi_i$, $\xi_{ij}$ be the corresponding matrices (so $\xi_0$ is the matrix with $1$ off the diagonal, $\xi_i$ is similar but has $-1$ on the $i$-th row and $i$-th column, and $\xi_{ij}$ has both $i$-th and $j$-th rows and columns inverted).
Note that $\sum_{i = 1}^n \xi_i = (n - 4) \xi_0$ and $\sum_{j \neq i} \xi_ij = (n - 4) \xi_i - \xi_0$.
We see that if $n \neq 4$, then the matrices $\xi_{ij}$ corresponding to vectors $\eta_{ij}$ with exactly two $-1$ entries form the basis required.
For $n=4$ this does not work as $\xi_{12} = \xi_{34}$, $\xi_{13} = \xi_{24}$, $\xi_{14} = \xi_{23}$. We need some ad hoc basis specifically for this case.

That makes sense, thank you! I was also thinking about using $\eta_{ij}$'s and observed that it did work for small $n$'s except $n=4$, but was not able to prove it for a general $n$: here's the link. Your explanation is detailed and very clear. Thank you again!
